# Raoult's Law and Boiling Point Elevation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, temperature, ideal-gas, liquid-state

Raoult's Law states that vapor pressure decreases when a non-volatile solute is present.

Boiling point is when vapor pressure = ambient pressure.

Since vapor pressure is less, shouldn't the energy required to reach the boiling point be less? Why doesn't the boiling point decrease then?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't think that the boiling point changes when the total air pressure is 0.5 atm instead of 1 atm?